# loading a jSON file locally without using jQuery ?

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, web

I'm new to javascript and web dev. I have been trying to figure out a way to parse a JSON file in a folder locally on my computer right now. I was attempting to use jQuery's getJSON function but it doesn't seem to work. I also saw a post on using XMLHttpRequest. Since it's a local file, I don't think either of the method works. What's a proper way of doing it before doing JSON.parse() ? There are many posts about this topic but I still haven't found one about avoiding http protocol.

Comment: Put that file in public folder on web server and to get the file data,  use jQuery's getJSON function....make sure your request path should be same as script src path( means you can access file via broswer)

Answer (score 0):

By design - when running on a browser - Javascript is not allowed to access your system files. You will need to serve the JSON on a local server and load from that.